# Could not Autowire - JdbcTemplate in Jetty Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty

When deploying my Spring Boot WAR to a standalone jetty instance, I get this error on server startup:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'testController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.projects.testing.controller.TestController.template
```

If I run my server with the packaged Jetty instance, everything works fine, but as I said, fails to run on a standalone Jetty.

This is the code for my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/base")
class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private TestJdbcService testJbdcService;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Test", response = TestObj.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity getActivity(@RequestHeader(value = "user-id") String user-id) {
        List<TestObj> testObjs;
        try {
            testObjs = testJbdcService.get(user-id, template);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return log(e, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, slf4jLogger, Error.Levels.ERROR);
        } finally {
            try {
                template.getDataSource().getConnection().close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                slf4jLogger.warn(String.format("Could not close connection! %s", e.getMessage()), e);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(testObjs, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And for my `TestJdbcService`:

```
@Service
public class TestJdbcService {
    public List<TestObj> get(String user-id, JdbcTemplate template) throws Exception {
        String someSQL = "SELECT ... "
        PreparedStatement statement = template.getDataSource().getConnection().prepareStatement(someSQL);
        // Do some stuff...
        return someTestList;
    }
}
```

Finally, the code for my `main` class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestService extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        EnvConfig.initialize();
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder) {
        System.out.println("LOADED CONFIGURE");
        return applicationBuilder.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<TenderfootService> applicationClass = TestService.class;
}
```

I have all my database settings properly configured in a `applications.properties` file, and when run with the built in jetty server, can easily query for objects. What could be causing the JdbcTemplate to not be autowired?

EDIT:

Full stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.test.controller.testController.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.annotation.ContainerInitializer.callStartup(ContainerInitializer.java:140) [jetty-plus-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter.doStart(ServletContainerInitializersStarter.java:63) [jetty-annotations-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:330) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1404) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1366) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772) [jetty-server-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:262) [jetty-servlet-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:520) [jetty-webapp-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:198) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileChanged(WebAppProvider.java:409) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileChanged(ScanningAppProvider.java:70) [jetty-deploy-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportChange(Scanner.java:664) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:532) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329) [jetty-util-9.3.9.v20160517.jar:9.3.9.v20160517]
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate com.test.controller.testController.template; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace of the failure?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Just added it

Comment: There's no `JdbcTemplate` in the context. I'd guess that means that it hasn't been auto-configured but it's not clear why. If you run your app with a `debug=true` system property the auto-configuration report will be logged. It should show why a `JdbcTemplate` wasn't auto-configured.